# Set Individual Product's Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart for a particular customer group

Tags: magento2, product, shopping-cart-price-rules, qty-increment, qty

I'm looking to setup a particular product with a minimum order quantity but only for a single customer group ("Wholesale"). Is there a way to do this using the core Magento 2 functionality? Barring that, is there an extension out there available to get this accomplished?

I know that I can edit a particular product and under the Advanced Inventory set the Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart value, but this then applies to all customer groups, and I need to target just a single one instead.

CLARIFICATION::
I need to be able to set the minimum quantity for **just one product** and for **just one customer group**. Here is a screenshot of the Advanced Inventory window where the value is that I need to set based on the customer group:[image]

Comment: Hello @dmandave have you checked my answer ?

Comment: I did Aditya, but unfortunately they don't get to the root of my issue, see my clarification above.

Comment: Okay, let me check

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I need exactly this also

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

---

> Admin -> Stores -> Configuration

[image]

For individual settings, go to product details AND Click Advanced Inventory

> **go to** Catalog > Inventory > Product Stock Options.

[image]

> In **Product Stock Options**, find 2 sections: **Maximum Qty Allowed** in
>   Shopping Cart and **Minimum Qty Allowed** in Shopping Cart.

[image]

In **Maximum Qty Allowed** in Shopping Cart, enter a number to determine the maximum quantity for products added to cart.

In **Minimum Qty Allowed** in Shopping Cart, pick customer group and assign the minimum order quantity to that group.

---

**Solution 2 (extension)**

---

[Min/Max Order Quantity](https://bsscommerce.com/magento-minimum-maximum-order-quantity-per-category-magento-2.html) for Magento 2.

- to set minimum and maximum order quantity for both customer groups
  and entire product category

[image]

Comment: Thanks for these Aditya, but unfortunately I need to set a minimum QTY at the Product level (not at the Cart level) so I'm afraid neither of these solutions will get me where I need to be.