# How to set a minimum qty 2 of specific category - Magento2

Tags: magento2.3, category-products, quantity

How to set minimum qty for specific category?

For example: I have 2 categories.

one -  test
second - test2

For test categories products : I want minimum qty should be 2.
and test2 categories customer can order 1.

Comment: Can you specify your requirement in details.

Comment: you want to set minimum qty for products ???

Comment: please check my updated question.

Comment: This might help. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245621/set-individual-products-minimum-qty-allowed-in-shopping-cart-for-a-particular-c
here they are giving quantity limit to customer group and category. But you can tweak little to get your output.

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not have a feature of minimum qty at Category label. Magento has the feature of min qty at the product label.

Min qty at category label is creating confusion because when you have assigned multiple categories that time it makes confusion. Then have to decide which category, you have selected for calculation of min qty. So, my suggestion that avoids this type of logic.